# What are possible variations of this question on distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory

> c) Show that, if $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\Bbb R)$ satisfies $f'=0$, then $f$ is a regular distribution associated with a constant function.

I know how this question is solved:

[image]

Can anyone suggest possible alternatives/variations of this question, i.e. similar exercises to the one above?

Comment: Answer to your title question:  "**Yes I can.**"  (Please learn how to write a clear, cogent, and appropriate question.)

Comment: Hello David, I'm sorry if I offended you, can I have some advice, this questions to me seems very unique and I'm trying to get a wider understanding.

Comment: You didn't offend me.  It is just that you need to learn how to ask better questions.  If I asked "Do you know who the third president of the United States is?"  You could answer perfectly correctly:  "Yes I *do* know!"  And it wouldn't help me at all.  The *proper* question would be instead "Who is the third president of the United States?"  See the difference?  See (now) the deep problem in your title question?  Care to edit and fix it?

Comment: How's that, I made a few edits?

Comment: @MicroscooterMan what exactly are you looking for? I could say a variation is "Show that if $f=0$ then its integral is constant" but I don't see how that would help anyone.

Comment: You could potentially do one where the distributional solution is the dirac delta, that is quite a common one

Comment: Hi George, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Do you want alternative proofs of the given exercise or do you want other similar statements to prove as exercises?

Comment: Hi @md2perpe, I ideally want alternative exercises? I want enough so I get a general context of what to do when these type of questions are sprung upon me?

Comment: Do you just want exercises similar to the shown one or also other basic distribution theory exercises?

Comment: Hi Md2perpe, I would love exercises similar to the one shown?

Answer (score 0):

A harder question is to show that every distribution $T$ on an open interval $I$ admits a primitive, that is a distribution $S$ on $I$ such that $S^\prime = T$.